# Simple online shopping site in PHP

Tags: php, online-payment, shopping-cart

I'm after a very simple PHP shop:

- not Opencart, PrestaShop, Woocommerce nor Magento as these are far too complicated, slow and too big for my current needs
- to run in PHP
- simple admin system for adding items, and preferably an api that would allow me to gather sales data for my own custom inventory system and also update inventory externally
- simple paypal payment system
- simple template system
- no plugins needed to add basic options such as variations, categories, tags
- internal cart for storing items which will be sent to paypal
- optional log-in for buying items
- a cache system (file-based) for items
- overall, to be a relatively simple system that would allow updating as necessary

I realise I could make something relatively simple in Laravel, but I'm looking to cut a few corners!

Comment: Do you have a database? Could you please detail "*add basic options*"?

Comment: I have a database and have updated the q

Comment: Please add to the question what database engine you have.

Comment: what ever database engine is needed. `apt-get` is pretty handy at times

Comment: Edit your question to add that info, we can't guess if you don't add it.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard good words about litecart. It's simple it runs in PHP, HTML5 and jQuery and seems to have faster files and database table to manager than the most common eShop Packages.

Have a look

https://www.litecart.net/comparison

Comment: i actually came across it, but couldn't find anyone else using it! the facebook group only has 188 likes!